# How to replace the multiple bracket?

Tags: c#

I have multiple bracket in the string.

So, i want to replace to empty for all multiple bracket.

for example,

```
string str = "111(222(333(444())))555(666(77(8888)))()";
var eliminateBracket = Regex.Replace(str, @"\([^)]*\)", "");
```

in this case i have result is "111))555))".

Howerver it need to result is "111555" except the all bracket.

Please help to me about this. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't pattern `\(|\)` do the trick?

Comment: No, this one pattern is not work. when i using this pattern, it result is "111222333444555666778888". This is not what i want.

Comment: What do you think `[^)]` means in your regex?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the numbers in the bracket? If so, result should be 111 only because your closing brackets are less than the open brackets after 111.

Comment: Yes. Correct. But, the rsult should be "111555". Because, "555" not in parentheses also.

Comment: Why this question got downvoted? it's a very solid question to match recursive brackets.

Answer (score 3):

this string `111(222(333(444()))555(666(77(8888)))()` missed a `)` before 555, or contains an extra `(` right after `111`,
you can find it out with code below:

```
    string str = "111(222(333(444()))555(666(77(8888)))()";
    var eliminateBracket = ReplaceBrackets(str);

    static string ReplaceBrackets(string input) {
        string regex = @"\([^()]*\)";
        string result = input;
        string previous = input;

        while (previous.Length !=
            (result = Regex.Replace(result, regex, "")).Length
            ) {
            previous = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

So the final string is `111(222555`.

Correct the given string to `111(222(333(444())))555(666(77(8888)))()` and it will show your expected result `111555`.

Comment: Thank you so much. as your mentioned the sample is wrong. 
Anyway, your sample code is perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @Song no problem. your question is solid, but I think you have to make it more clear for others not to misunderstand what you really need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [string.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) to replace the "(" and ")"

```
string str = "111(222(333(444()))555(666(77(8888)))()".Replace("(","").Replace(")","");
```

If you expected result 111555 you could use this reqex

```
 string str = "111(222(333(444())))555(666(77(8888)))()";
        var eliminateBracket = Regex.Replace(str, @"\([^)]*\)*\)", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, your sample will be replace the only "(" and ")". But, i need to replace data within "()". So, this sample result should be "111555".

Comment: @Song, I thought you need remove only "(" and ")".  Updated for you

Comment: @MaxMokrousov your expression not work with `111((1)222(333(444())))555(666(77(8888)))()`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to remove anything in brackets, without regex.

```
public static string RemoveAnythingInBrackets(string input)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return input;
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Stack<char> bracket = new Stack<char>();
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        if(c == '(')
        {
            bracket.Push(c);
        }
        else if(c == ')' && bracket.Peek() == '(')
        {
            bracket.Pop();
        }
        else if(!bracket.Any())
        {
            result.Append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```